# How to create Installer for MAC for a java application with dependent libs?

Tags: java, c++, linux, macos, installation

I am a noob in creating installer. I have a java application that uses C++ shared Library through JNI. Now I want to create an installer for MAC OSX. And as the shared libraries are needed to run the app so we need to copy the dependent libs folder also. I have tried in several ways and searched thousands of time but everybody is referencing their tools for this purpose. Can anyone suggest me that how can I create installer for MAC OSX?

Please give a full manual or howtos as I have mentioned earlier that I am a noob.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the shared libraries part of your software, or are they open-source, third-party software?

Comment: On linux, you can have a shell script which does it or you need to create a package-manager specific package.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Start with picking one or the other: OS X or Linux.  Then start with asking how to create a distributable application package for that OS.  Then after you have that, an installer.

Comment: @whiskeyspider I thought installer in MAC and linux will be similar as both are UNIX like OS, that's why asked for two platforms in a single question. However, I have edited my question.

Comment: @MarcGlisse the shared libraries are part of my software.

Comment: You can put your dependent libraries into your fat JAR and load them manually at runtime with System.load() and by using this trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file You can create a Mac installer (app file) with PackR or with JNDT (I'm the author of this Ant based tool).